# Declaring multiple functions in a particular javascript class

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why this does not work, but if you comment out the countGrin function, it works perfectly fine:

```
var DetectEmoticons = {
    countHappy: function(data) {
        var pattern = new RegExp("[:=]-?[)|\\]]|[(|\\[]-?[:=]", "g");
        var count = (data.match(pattern) || []).length;
        return count;
    }
    countGrin: function(data) {
        var pattern = new RegExp("[:=]-?[D]", "g");
        var count = (data.match(pattern) || []).length;
        return count;
    }
}
alert(DetectEmoticons.countHappy("=) :) :] :[ ]="));
alert(DetectEmoticons.countGrin(":D =D"));
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9BTAb/

Comment: You're missing the comma between the two functions

Comment: You're missing a comma. Also, that's not a class, that's an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe you lacked the `,` after the first function [SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9BTAb/1/)

```
var DetectEmoticons = {
    countHappy: function(data) {
        var pattern = new RegExp("[:=]-?[)|\\]]|[(|\\[]-?[:=]", "g");
        var count = (data.match(pattern) || []).length;
        return count;
    }, //put a comma here
    countGrin: function(data) {
        var pattern = new RegExp("[:=]-?[D]", "g");
        var count = (data.match(pattern) || []).length;
        return count;
    }
}
```